# Simple Chiptune software for game music

Tags: music

I'm looking for the "Microsoft Paint" equivalent of chiptune music creation software.

Something very simple (I use Bfxr for sound effect generation which has been perfect for me) where I could save in .wav file format or something similar.

By "chiptune" I mean old school (8-bit or 80s era) sounds like what the SID chip could do on the Commodore 64.

The only software I've come across so far has been just too complex, the learning curve too high, or the price tag too high.

Any advice is welcome!

Comment: Unfortunetly, asking for software recommendations is off topic for Game Dev SE. We do, however, have a Software Recommendation SE. Try there, but be sure to read through their help centre regarding how to ask an ontopic question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Shrinking Planet - Brackeys](https://ldjam.com/events/ludum-dare/38/shrinking-planet)

The developer of this game used [Bosca Ceoil](http://boscaceoil.net/), to create chiptunes for his game.
The developer has a YouTube channel called "Brackeys" where he teaches Game Development.

Comment: Please do not answer blatantly off-topic questions.